# Disable extension for some customer group Magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7. I have added free gift extension to my magento store.I don't want to give free gift option for some customer groups.So I need to disable this extension to certain customer groups.Is it possible if,yes How would i do it.

Comment: What is the free extension that you used now?

Comment: Gift for product bought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get customer group id using

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Ref link : http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.in/2010/12/get-customer-group-id-in-magento.html
and put your code inside the loop

Comment: This solution seems to be pretty easy one.. I thought to provide an answer, but this is simpler than my one.. You can go with this answer..... Good solution @alamelu